# PHP fwrite output always 4096 bytes

Tags: php, fwrite

I'm using simple fwrite in a while loop to write retreived data from my database to a .txt file, but the output file always has a filesize of 4096 bytes.

```
$sql = 'SELECT company_name, address1, postal_code, city, phone FROM `DE_OZ_company_address` WHERE `phone` != "" LIMIT 15000';

$result = mysqli_query ($con,$sql);
$i = 0;

$fp = fopen('data.txt', 'a');    

while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()){

$name = $row['company_name'];
$strasse = $row['address1'];
$plz = $row['postal_code'];
$ort = $row['city'];
$nummer = $row['phone'];

$i++;

$data = "\"".$name."\";\"".$strasse."\";\"".$plz."\";\"".$ort."\";\"".$nummer."\" \r\n";
fwrite($fp, $data);
}

fclose($fp);
mysqli_close($con);
```

EDIT : Some more code (DB connection is correct)

I found this in my PHP.ini : "**output_buffering : 4096**"
Can this causes the limitation of the output file?

Is it possible to output/save about 5 mio. rows at once without getting time-out issue?

@admin : I'm not asking to fix my script. I'm just asking why the output is always only 4096 bytes, when retrieving 15.000 rows from the database.

Comment: Can you show more of your code, one line isn't enough to see what your doing.

Comment: In general: sure, you can output as much data as you want in a loop.

Comment: The output buffering setting has nothing to do with writing to a file. We do not know why your file is limited to 4096 bytes, we do not see enough code to suggest that it should be anything else.